# Impact of Aufs on Filesystem performance

Tags: docker

I am running an apache2/php application in an Azure App service on Containers. When I read files from the local filesystem it takes around 4 times longer than it did in the elastic beanstalk deployment on Amazon Linux. (66 files, totaling around 287187 take 2ms instead of 0.5)

From what I see in `mount` the container root is mounted on aufs, but not overlayfs.

## Reading it from the image layer

The documentation says:

> The file does not exist in the container layer: If a container opens a file for read access and the file does not already exist in the container layer, the storage driver searches for the file in the image layers, starting with the layer just below the container layer. It is read from the layer where it is found.

I am curious what actual performance impact I can expect on this and if it could be the reason for this difference.

## Moving it to the container layer

It also states:

> The file exists in both the container layer and the image layer: If a container opens a file for read access and the file exists in the container layer and one or more image layers, the file is read from the container layer. Files in the container layer obscure files with the same name in the image layers.

So when I `mv` the directory containing the files to be read to a different directory and back to the original one, it would expect to move it to the container layer. The value does not change anyway.
Would this work as I would expect?

Comment: What? Is that a question? It makes no sense. Please try rewriting this.

Comment: I am trying to add more context

Comment: Much better, thx :)

Comment: aufs was for docker prior v18.06 and is lower performance than overlay2, the preferred option. You should not be running older less secure versions of docker and you should not be using aufs. If this is the only option provided by Azure then you have a security risk and performance impact/cost due to the docker implementation being very old. If this is the only option on Azure then using Azure cannot be recommended.